# Wrong answer of openMP code in c

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote a program that searches for an element in an integer array of  100000000 and initialized it to i+1(i is index of the element). Now in this i am searching for 73500320, and updates integer 'me' to 1 if it is found, 'me' was initialized to -1. But when i print me, it sometimes prints as -1 and sometimes as 1. (It should always be found!) I can't figure out the error...

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    int thread = omp_get_thread_num();
    int num_thread=omp_get_num_threads();
    int beginpos = (thread + 0) * (100000000 / num_thread);
    int endpos   = (thread + 1) * (100000000 / num_thread);
    for (i = beginpos; i < endpos; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp flush(done)
        if (done == 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (a[i] == 73500320)
        { 
            /* Inform the other threads that we found the element. */
            done = 1;
            #pragma omp flush(done)
            me = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok you inform the other thread that done had changed but you should lock around "each read/write of "done"

Comment: This code nowhere sets `me` to `-1`.

Comment: agree but it can be explain because you set and notify done before setting me to 1. I cannot test for now so I will not answer but try to set "me" before "done"

Comment: it looks like [break] directly break the parallel loop. you may read that blog http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/06/29/breaking-out-of-loops-in-openmp/ it describe several way to solve similar issues.

Comment: modified the code according to the suggestions. But did not get any satisfactory result. Its still the same giving variable results. The link mentioned continues the for loop even after the computation is done. i am trying to finish the loop as soon as computation is over.

Comment: I agree that stopping all the loop the sooner would be the better :) so to be strict and without being able to test, i would say : declare all shared var as "shared" on the parallel section (done, me) 2) protect those var against RW data race with an [ open mp critical ] and last but not the least add an [ OpenMP barrier ] after the parallel section to be sure that all previous thread join that point before displaying [ me ]

Comment: `i` should be private. Either declare it inside the parallel region or add the `private(i)` clause.

Answer (score 0):

as the break statement is really not something you can use in an open mp loop, consider the following code

it use an OpenMP static schedule (similar to the logic you added at the beginning of your parallel region.

so I is implicitly private, me and done are explicitly shared, and I agree that all thread have to finish their work and cannot go out the sooner. but on VS'2012 for example if i try to put a break in a [parallel for loop] construct i get "error C3010: 'break' : jump out of OpenMP structured block not allowed"

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(me, done)
for (int i = 0; i <  100000000; i++)
{
    if (done == -1)
    {
    if (a[i] == 73500320)
    { 
        cout << "thread " << omp_get_thread_num() << " found at i=" << i << endl;
        me = 1;
        done = 1;          
    }
    }
}

cout << me << endl;
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct but the problem is the loop does not stop if the element is found... i want to stop the loop as soon as the element is found...

Comment: but you can't .... OpenMP spec is clear you cannot have other exit point than the closing bracket. So if you express the problem by " I would parallelized/split a find first task and output the result the sooner" OpenMP can do it but you have to use the task construct....